# Grafana using Stackdriver ( Kubernetes )

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, stackdriver

I was trying to create some graphs using Grafana and Stackdriver as a datasource, so far using GCE I'm able to see a autocomplete filter but for Kubernetes I cannot see any example and autocomplete queries to retrieve the values from my cluster, anyone have figured out how to make it work giving some filter examples?

Answer (score 1):

I've never implemented this solution but I've seen some official tutorials from Google explaing all the the [configuration](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/introducing-stackdriver-as-a-data-source-for-grafana) process for both GCE and GKE. It might help you